# Can't Display Form Errors in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, blogs, codeigniter-3

I am Creating a Blogging Application with Codeigniter. So therefor i have created admin panel for admin. But on my new article controller i cant display form errors. Here is my code.

**Add Article and Store Article Controllers**

```
public function add_article()
{
    $this->load->model('dashboardmodel');
    $username = $this->dashboardmodel->get_username();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('admin/add_article', ['user'=>$username]);
}
public function store_article()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">', '</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Post Title', 'required|trim|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Post Content', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $title = $this->input->post('title');
        $body = $this->input->post('body');
        echo 'Successful';
    } else {
        return redirect('admin/add_article');
    }
}
```

**Add Article View**

```
    <?php
    include_once('admin_header.php');
    ?>
    <div class="container">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>New Post</legend>
//Here ERRORS SHOULD BE DISPLAYED
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <?php echo form_open('admin/store_article', ['class'=>'form-horizontal']);
    if ($error = $this->session->flashdata('login_failed')) : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
      <?= $error ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-10">
          <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'title', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Post Title', 'value'=>set_value('title')]); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <?php echo form_textarea(['name'=>'body', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Post Content']); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <?php echo form_reset(['name'=>'reset', 'value'=>'Reset', 'class'=>'btn btn-default']),
        form_Submit(['type'=>'submit', 'value'=>'Publish', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary']); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>

    </div>

    <?php
    include_once('admin_footer.php');
    ?>
```

Dont What's Going On but i am Stuck in it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when the form submission contains errors, you redirect to the page again, which refreshes the page and all errors are gone. What you need to do is replace your `return redirect('admin/add_article');` line with actually loading the same view again, which would contain the errors this time. And since you load other things for the view, you'll have to replace it with this whole code (which is the same as the other method so maybe you should give the structure of this code more thought):

```
$this->load->model('dashboardmodel');
$username = $this->dashboardmodel->get_username();
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->view('admin/add_article', ['user'=>$username]);
```

Comment: Thanks for Responding but when i load a view instead of redirecting url will be like http://example/index.php/admin/store_article but i want add_article instead store_article

Comment: You really just need to combine both methods into one method. You don't need 2 methods to add an article. Just add an if else statement in the store_article method with the code of the add_article method running if form submission fails, else continue with the store_article code.